# Javascript function returning [object HTMLSelectElement] string instead of <select> HTML tag

Tags: javascript, html, string-literals, template-literals

I´m trying to create and call a function that builds a `<select>` item and returns this item to be rendered on the screen.

However, it renders the text "[object HTMLSelectElement]" on the screen instead of the `<select>` element that I want. In the Chrome console, though, it renders the `<select>` element perfectly.

```js
function renderSelect(selectOptions) {
  var select = document.createElement("select");

  for (let index = 0; index < selectOptions.length; index++) {
    const element = selectOptions[index];

    select.insertAdjacentHTML(
      "beforeend",
      `<option value="${element}">${element}</option>`
    );
  }

  // This shows the <select> element perfectly in the console
  console.log(select)

  return select;
}

////////// BELOW IS THE FUNCTION CALL IN ANOTHER (WHICHEVER) PART OF THE CODE

// This renders "[object HTMLSelectElement]" on the screen instead of the <select> element
`${renderSelect(selectOptions)}`;
```

Comment: _"This renders "[object HTMLSelectElement]" on the screen instead of the <select> element"_ - `\`${...}\`` is a template literal that evalutes the expression in `{ ... }` into a string. If you don't want a string, then don't convert it into a string.

Comment: @Andreas Right, but the hidden question here is why doesn't `console.log(select)` also log that string

Comment: You can simply append the returned element, alternatively if you feel you must use it in a template literal you could use `outerHTML`. `${renderSelect(selectOptions).outerHTML}`;

Comment: @JamesThorpe _"why doesn't `console.log(select)` also log that string"_ - Why should it? `.log()` doesn't convert its argument(s) into strings.

Comment: @Andreas I didn't say it should - just commenting that that's the hidden question that the OP has.

Comment: @Andreas thank you, but the problem is that I need the result of the function (the `<select>` element) inside another template literal. That's why I called the function inside ${...} and not directly